# How find constant term of quadratic with square already completed?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Suppose I have a quadratic polynomial in two variables `x` and `y` in which the squares with respect to `x` and `y` have already been completed:

```
 q = -72 + 9 (-2 + x)^2 + 4 (3 + y)^2 ;
```

How might I extract the "constant" part `-72` of this expression?

(Note that I am *not* asking how to find the constant term of the polynomial; I know you can do that by simply replacing `x` and `y` with `0`.)

Answer (score 3):

```
♯ = # & @@ # &
♯ @ q
```

> -72

**tl;dr**

```
♯♯ = # & @ ## & @@ # &

♯♯ @ q
```

> -72

Comment: Sharp! :-P --  +1

Comment: `# & @@ q` suffices ;-} +1

Comment: @MichaelE2, thank you..

Comment: @ciao, what was i thinking:)

Comment: +2 for cleverness, -1 for giving me headaches. ;P

Comment: Thank you @J. M. Headaches is (are?) an undocumented side effect of pure functions:)

Answer (score 2):

```
q /. Power -> (0 &)
```

> -72

Notes:

Since

```
0&[x,y]
```

> 0

then

```
Power[x, y]/.Power->(0&)
```

> 0

and

```
q /. Power -> (0 &)
```

> -72

Additional ways using `ReplaceAll` for OP's specific example:

```
q /. _Power -> 0 (* thanks: @Guesswhoitis. *)
q /. Times -> (0&)
q /. _Times -> 0
```

and using `Block` (temporarily re-defining `Power` or `Times` as `0&`):

```
Block[{Power = 0 &}, q]
Block[{Times = 0 &}, q]
```

Note that none of the above would work for

```
q1 = -72 (a^2) + 9 (-2 + x)^2 + 4 (3 + y)^2
```

since the constant term in `q1` contains elements with head `Times` and `Power`.

Comment: Would `q /. _Power -> 0` work also?

Comment: @J. M., yes... that's better.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, thank you for the edit.

Comment: One could argue that `-72(a - 0)^2` is part of the "square" terms…

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think this is easier than I thought:

```
   c = First[List @@ q]
(* -72 *)
```

Is there a yet easier way, or some alternate ways?

(Sorry, I had not intended to post something I could so quickly answer myself!)

Comment: Assuming poly in form of question, `First@q` suffices, as does e.g. `Cases[q, _?NumericQ]`...

Comment: @ciao: ah yes, the default sort order will put the constant term first!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use <s>`Cases`</s> `DeleteCases` on the default level 1 (I overlooked an assumption in my original use of `Cases`):

```
q = -72 + 9 (-2 + x)^2 + 4 (3 + y)^2;
DeleteCases[q, _?(!FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ Variables[q]] &)]
(*  -72  *)
```

---

A few other methods and examples.  One problem with using `First` is that it assumes the constant is first, which I believe will be true if the constant is a simple number.  It seems likely the OP has in mind that the constant term will be a single integer, but the scope of the problem is naturally larger.  Aside from some numeric expressions not being sorted so that they appear before terms containing variables, there is also the possibility of symbolic constants.  Here are some approaches to problems for which `First` fails. They use `DeleteCases` in the same way as above; the differences are in how constants are determined.

```
q = GoldenRatio^2 + (a + 2)^2 + 4 (b + 1)^2;  (* < System symbolic constant *)
DeleteCases[q, _?(! FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ Variables[q]] &)]
First@q
(*
  GoldenRatio^2
  (2 + a)^2                                   (* < First failed *)
*)

q = 1 + Sqrt[2] + (a + 2)^2 + 4 (b + 1)^2;    (* < more than one constant term *)
DeleteCases[q, _?(FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ Variables[q]] &)]
First@q
(*
  (2 + a)^2 + 4 (1 + b)^2
  1
*)

q = (a + 2)^2 + 4 (b + 1)^2 + C[1] - 5;
myvars = {a, b};                              (* < user-specified variables *)
DeleteCases[q, _?(! FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ myvars] &)]
First[q]
(*
  -5 + C[1]
  -5
*)

SetAttributes[c, Constant];                   (* < user-specified Constants *)
q = (a + 2)^2 + 4 (b + 1)^2 + (c - 1)^2;
DeleteCases[q, _?(Dt[#] =!= 0 &)]
First@q
ClearAll[c];
(*
  (-1 + c)^2
  (2 + a)^2
*)
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. It does, though, seem more complicated than my method.

Comment: @murray It is certainly more complicated, but as for correctness, I suppose it depends on what you may assume about the polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, nobody brought up this possibility:

```
SeriesCoefficient[-72 + 9 (-2 + x)^2 + 4 (3 + y)^2, {x, 2, 0}, {y, -3, 0}]
   -72
```

where it is assumed that you know the terms subtracted from the corresponding variables.